Changing spring in Qidi Q1 Pro and Voltage Input
I am here to seek your guidance on two issues regarding my Qidi Q1 Pro printer.
Firstly, I am looking into replacing a missing component that is essential for adjusting the height of the printing bed on my printer. Despite my attempts to adjust it following the provided instructions, the bed height remains unchanged. As a newcomer to the world of 3D printing, I am considering sourcing this replacement part externally. Can someone provides me with the specifications of the missing component (is this a spring that missing?) and offer instructions on how to properly install it?
Secondly, I am facing a voltage input dilemma with my printer. The current input voltage setting on the printer is 110V, while the power supply in my home is 220V. I have identified a switch next to the printer's power supply that allows for toggling the voltage input from 115V to 230V. Can simply switching this voltage input solve the compatibility issue I am experiencing with the power supply in my home?

Hi and welcome to 3D printing.SE! SE websites are driven by questions and answers, your question contains multiple questions which makes it more difficult to answer as there are multiple answers. Please read the [help] section, accessible through the button with the question mark at the top right menu and read [ask]. Please split up your question by adding the other question in a separate question!

To answer your first question: The QIDI Q1 pro has auto bed leveling, so I assume that the bed height is compensated by the bed probe.
To answer your second question: The switch is on the power supply to let you choose the voltage that your wall outlet delivers. In the 110 V setting the output will assume that the input voltage is 110 V and if instead it receives 230 V, it will give your printer twice the power that it needs and that is probably more than it can handle.
TL/DR: Do not turn on the printer before switching to 230 V!
